# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime with stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, openquery

[Using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64 SP1]

I am trying to use some form of `GETDATE()` to pass today's date to a stored procedure inside `OPENQUERY()`, but I keep getting the error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCalcProjection, Line 0
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Here is the code (spCalcProjection takes a `datetime`):

```
SELECT top 1 multi FROM OPENQUERY([production], 'exec proddb.dbo.spCalcProjection "GETDATE()"')
```

If I use `2014-05-22` or any literal in place of `GETDATE()` then I have no problem and get the correct, expected result. If I use some other functionality like `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` or `CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112)` then I get the above error again.

Comment: Why are you using doble quotes in `GETDATE()`?, try without them

Comment: @Lamak I am using double quotes because they are required, otherwise a syntax error is generated.  Those, or double single-quotes, are required to escape the t-sql.

Comment: using two single quotes is quite different than double quotes. Which one are you using, they are **not** equivalent at all

Comment: @Lamak I've tried both.

Comment: And as I said, you should try using none of them. Listen, using the double quotes is a syntax error, won't work. And the 2 single quotes to "escape" the string concatenation is also not needed and probably the source of your error since it's trying to concatenate `GETDATE()` as if it were a string

Comment: @Lamak I have tried the code without any quotes and that results in syntax errors. If I use a literal, _e.g._ `2014-05-22` then everything works as expected.

Comment: Well, what is the data type of the parameter for your sp?

Comment: `datetime` - updated orig question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from elsewhere that I will use:

```
SELECT top 1 multi FROM OPENQUERY([production], 'DECLARE @dt datetime SELECT @dt = GETDATE() exec proddb.dbo.spCalcProjection @dt')
```

This avoids having to create any additional objects in the db.

Answer (score 1):

Conrad, posting original syntax error for GETDATE() without double quotes could help more than you think. I also don't see why would you need to escape the function here. (Sorry, can't add to your thread with Lamak, not enough reputation for comments). Also, why do you need an open query to call your sp? When you say SQL Server 2008 R2, is it both on the calling side and on your [production] server? If the other end is not SQL Server it might not have GETDATE() function. If the other end is SQL Server you don't need OpenQuery.

**[UPDATE]**
I think I have your answer. You cannot use a function as a parameter for stored procedure. Has nothing to do with open query. What you can do, you can replace that stored procedure with table-valued function. I just tried it and it worked.

Definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestFun
(
    @TestDateParam datetime
)
RETURNS 
@RetTable TABLE 
(
    Line nvarchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RetTable
    SELECT aString
        FROM sometable
        WHERE aDate = @TestDateParam

    RETURN 
END
```

Call:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbname.dbo.TestFun(GETDATE())
```

Comment: I need to call the SP via `OPENQUERY()` because this is in a view. I am calling from [production] as well as to it.  Here's the error when I don't use any quotes: 

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "production" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Updated my answer with proposed solution.

Comment: This was my backup solution - I was hoping to not have to create an additional TVF in the db.